# Unstaged changes show file as deleted even though it exists

Tags: git

A file in my repository causes me quite a headache. `git status` shows it under "Changes not staged for commit" as "deleted" and it also shows the exact same file under "Untracked files"! The file exists quite definitely on my disk and also on the remote repository. If I delete the file, the entry in "Untracked files" disappears but the other one stays.

Now for my questions: How does this make any sense? And how do I fix it?

```
$ git checkout -- .

$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm ..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- ..." to discard changes in working directory)

    deleted:    solution02/exercise02.txt 

Untracked files:
  (use "git add ..." to include in what will be committed)

    solution02/exercise02.txt

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

$ git status --short
 D "solution02/exercise02.txt "
?? solution02/exercise02.txt

$ rm solution02/exercise02.txt

$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm ..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- ..." to discard changes in working directory)

    deleted:    solution02/exercise02.txt 

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

$ git status --short
 D "solution02/exercise02.txt "
```

Just to clarify: The first `git status` is the one which does not make any sense to me, because it lists the file as "deleted" under "Changes not staged for commit". But the file is not deleted. It exists.

Comment: Can you attach the commands and output ?

Comment: Something is amiss here. It would be helpful if you would paste the actual output of `git status --short` (without renaming files to `foo/bar.txt`): I suspect you may be on a Mac and running into issues with files with characters like `ü` in them.

Comment: @torek I am on Windows and the short output seems to suggest my repository has a filename that ends with whitespace. This would mean that `git checkout -- .` does not restore the file correctly, but trims the trailing whitespace from its name! Is this observation correct?

Comment: Yes, I think my observation is correct. `mv solution02/exercise02.txt 'solution02/exercise02.txt '` fixes my workspace and `git status` finally emits "nothing to commit, working tree clean". I think the fact that git is not able to clean up the working tree might be an actual bug in git (for Windows, at least).

Comment: Ah, it was whitespace rather than Unicode ... but yes, that definitely seems like a bug. (And Matthieu Moy's answer is the right one in this case.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens when the file was subtly renamed, i. e. When is name on disk doesn't match the name in the Git repository, even thought both names visually match. For example :

- If the name contains non ascii characters (accented letters), there can be several encodings for the same character. There were known issues with old versions of Git under Mac OS X due to UTF-8 normalization for example.
- There may be whitespace-only changes (e. g. a trailing space) in one of the names. `git status --short` will display more details about the file name (double quotes around the name if needed, ...) and may help here.

A solution is to rename the file back to the Git name. Doing an exact cut and paste of the "deleted" name may help.

EDIT: after your update in the actual output of commands, it turns out it's the second option: there's a trailing whitespace after "`exercise02.txt` " in the name of the file tracked by Git.

Comment: Note: In my case it was clearly Git's fault the file was "subtly renamed" in the first place. Git seems to have a bug which makes it remove trailing whitespace in filenames, on Windows at least.

Answer (score -1):

If you deleted the file manually it will show as untracked file in `git status`. But if you deleted the file using `git rm filename` it will be staged for commit automatically and when you run `git status` after this it will show as file deleted. So to summarize the below 2 commands

```
  rm filename
  git add filename
```

is equivalent to one line command
`git rm filename`

commit your changes  before you checkout to any other branch since it will show as files changed unless you commit changes even if you checkout to a different branch