# Git status shows file as deleted on local even though it was not deleted

Tags: git, github

I see a deleted local file on my working tree and it is driving me crazy. Here is what is happening:

I clone the remote repo to my local machine:

`git clone <my repo>`

I checkout master and view its status

```
git checkout master
git status
```

And even though I have not done anything with it, I see this file deleted from my local machine

```
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        deleted:    xyz.PNG

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

I can see this file on the remote repo. And sure enough, if I do:

```
git reset --hard HEAD

or

git checkout .
```

The file appears back and the status is clean again.

```
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

But if I checkout some other branch, and then switch back to master again, the delete message turns up again. It is almost as if there is something that is deleting this one specific file from my local every time I switch to master, but I have no idea what that would be.

I have looked at [Unstaged changes show file as deleted even though it exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47122134/unstaged-changes-show-file-as-deleted-even-though-it-exists)
and there does not seem to be a space in the filename (no quotes around file name):

```
git status --short
D xyz.PNG
```

Comment: Could this be a capitalization issue? `xyz.png` is not `xyz.PNG`.

Comment: I thought so at first, since I have seen that create unwanted "change" status before, but for some reason it keeps saying file deleted in local tree (and the file actually does disappear from the tree until I do a git reset)

Comment: Are you using a cloud syncing service (Dropbox, OneDrive, iCloud, etc.) for this directory?

Comment: Yes, I am (Onedrive on company's laptop). But this folder specifically where I have cloned the repo is not included in the folders that Onedrive syncs. I have been trying to figure out a way to trace what process is deleting the file, and while that did not lead anywhere, I did find that on Linux/WSL there is no issue. So it's likely something to do with windows or filenames.

Answer (score 0):

This:

> (and the file actually does disappear from the tree until I do a git reset)

is the most important item.  It means that Git isn't *lying* when it says that the file is deleted, but the deletion is not staged for commit.  The  `D xyz.PNG` (note that there's a *leading* space before the `D` here) as a short status means the same thing: the file has mysteriously gone missing from your working tree.  (Note that if you had removed it *yourself*, this would not be mysterious: it would be expected.)

The *second most important* thing is that your working tree is just a plain old set of directories-and-files (folders-and-files, if you prefer the "folder" term) on your computer.  *This means anything else on your computer can engage in a drive-by shooting and take out the files entirely*, and presumably this is what is happening.  If `git checkout` had failed to *check out* the file initially, Git should have noticed this and complained.  Without any complaint, that implies that `git checkout` was successful and placing the ordinary file into the ordinary directory on your computer.  *Something else* must have removed it.

[Your mission, should you choose to accept it](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Mission:_Impossible), is to find out *what this "something" is*.  It's not Git.  (Is it some sort of antivirus software?  If so, why does a later reset or checkout not get the same treatment?  Are you storing your working tree in a shared or cloud-synced location?)

Comment: But surely this is just repeating what the OP originally said: "It is almost as if there is something that is deleting this one specific file from my local every time I switch to master, but I have no idea what that would be."

Comment: @matt: Yes, I'm just turning it from "almost as if" to "something is". Perhaps I should also add that the *working tree* copy is quite separate from the *committed* copy, which remains there in the repository?

Comment: The odd thing is I got to know about this because another developer pointed out the same issue taking place on his local machine, so it is reproducible across machines. I am completely stumped by this. The file itself is completely unremarkable. It shares the same extension (.PNG) with a few other files in the same folder that are just fine. The name isn't unique. And yet every time I checkout master, like clockwork the file goes away only to come back when reset. I will try a few other things, and if somehow I find out the reason I will post here.